# HTML table formatting issue - parsing jSON object into an HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, html-table

I have some code that grabs a JSON objects and displays it in a HTML table, however the table is not displaying correctly.

I want the table to be displayed like this:

```
_________________
|    Product1    |
==================   
| 1852ak |  2016 |
==================
|   refurbished  |
__________________
```

Here is my code:

```
var product = {
  "name": "Product1",
  "model": "1852ak",
  "year": "2016",
  "details": "refurbished"
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var row = $('<tr>');
  row.append('<tr><td colspan = 2s>' + product.name + '</td></tr>');
  row.append('<tr><td>' + product.model + '</td></tr>');
  row.append('<td>' + product.year + '</td></tr>');
  row.append('<tr><td>' + product.details + '</td></tr>');
  $('#sample').append(row);
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You appear to be appending `<tr>` elements into your `row` `<tr>` element. Don't do that

Comment: Also, `colspan = 2s`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding rows to your existing rows.

In addition to this, you are considering the table to be one singular 'object', and are adding both the rows and the **cells** directly to the table. The table cells should be added to their containing **rows**.

What I would recommend doing is defining three separate rows as independent variables, then adding the cells to their respective rows. As the row has all of its content created, it gets added to the table:

```js
var product = {
  "name": "Product1",
  "model": "1852ak",
  "year": "2016",
  "details": "refurbished"
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#sample');
  var row1 = $('<tr>');
  var row2 = $('<tr>');
  var row3 = $('<tr>');
  row1.append('<td colspan = 2>' + product.name + '</td>');
  table.append(row1);
  row2.append('<td>' + product.model + '</td>');
  row2.append('<td>' + product.year + '</td>');
  table.append(row2);
  row3.append('<td colspan = 2>' + product.details + '</td>');
  table.append(row3);
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="sample"></table>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code:

```js
var product =
{
"name":"Product1",
"model":"1852ak",
"year":"2016",
"details":"refurbished"
}

$(document).ready(function()
    {
        var row =$('table');
        row.append ('<tr><td colspan = "2">' + product.name + '</td></tr>');     
        row.append('<tr><td>' +  product.model + '</td><td>' +  product.year + '</td></tr>');
        row.append ('<tr><td colspan = "2">' + product.details + '</td></tr></table>');   

    $('#sample').append(row);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sample"></div>
```

Presuming that `$("#sample")` is your table

Comment: Presumably, `#sample` is already a `<table>` in OP's code. Also, add `border="1"` to make your example table more obvious :)

Comment: No, your original answer was much better than this

Comment: @MatheusCuba Why are your appending table elements to a `div`... this is invalid markup hence the layout being messed up...